# Problems with generating links with special language specific charactors in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, special-characters

I'm browsing the web and stackoverflow now for quite a while and I don't seem to find the correct answer. I have the following issue in generating my URLs. I'm moving a project to Laravel and everything should work the same way as before.
Basically the issue is, when I add a new event with my form and catch the inputs with either `Input::get('name')` or `$_REQUEST['name']` I don't seem to be able to catch the charactors as I used to before.
In the old project I caught the characters and converted them to html entities like `&#252;` and then for my URL in this case it was a `ü` to `ue`. I even imported the same functions I used but they don't work. Here is my input control function from the old project, also preventing SQL injections:

```
function checkinput($rawstring,$replacespace=0){
        $newstring=str_replace(array("'",chr(34),"â","å","Å","ä","Ä","æ","Æ","è","É","é","ë","ĕ","Ö","ö","ó","ø","Ø","Ü",
                        "ü","ň","ñ","ß","č"),
                    array("&#39;","&#34;","&#226;","&#229;","&#197;","&#228;","&#196;","&#230;","&#198;","&#232;",
                        "&#201;","&#233;","&#235;","&#277;","&#214;","&#246;","&#243;","&#248;","&#216;","&#220;",
                        "&#252;","&#328;","&#241;","&#223;","&#269;"   ),$rawstring);

    if($replacespace==1){
        $newstring=str_replace(" ", "_", $newstring);
    }
    return $newstring;
}
```

Could you help me make that work again? I saw that there is supposed to be a `no-entities` option to be set somewhere in the Laravel config, but I can't find where to do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in the old project you used ISO-8859-1, now you are using UTF-8. Html entities are different for each. But anyway, don't use html entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this post, I finally found the answer for my issue. Actually not that hard, if you know what you're looking for :-)

I solved it with the htmlentities() php function, with some parameters, see below:

`$eventName = htmlentities(($_POST['name']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`

with this I got my entities, not exactly the way I wanted them, but at least I got them. 
my `ü` for instance was converted to `&uuml;` instead of the hex value `&#252;`. I adjusted the function, which converted the charactor back to `ue` for the URL and all works fine now.

Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change your charset page

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
```

or use/and

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["Name"], "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Bruno, thanks for the try, but both + combined or one at the time did not work and did not give me the wanted result.
Here is an URL generated, this should give a little bit more details about the problem.
http://dev.hobbyathletes.com/run/2nd-Schoa-Tr%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%9F-2045/
The special characters are converted into something like this above and I believe I need to catch them the way they look in this copied URL, When I open the URL the browser bar shows the special charactors as special charactors. This is a bit confusing for me...

Comment: Just to mention it: your second line, almost worked, it replaced the `ü` with `u` but not as I need it with `ue`.

Comment: Maybe

    htmlentities(urlencode($_POST["Name"]));